# Reload 2 php pages in iframes in sequence

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

I have an index page with iframes, two of the iframes I want to re-load in sequence, iframe1 at 20 seconds, then iframe2 20 seconds later, then iframe1 again in 20 seconds, then iframe2 again in 20 seconds, forever.

I have tried sleep() in php, , and other javascript.

Why does php and javascript not support a simple script pause?

do ( '1' < '2' ) {

sleep(20);

echo script type="text/javascript

echo 'parent.featuredBottom.location = "modules/featured-bottom.php"';

echo /script>

sleep(20);

echo script type="text/javascript

echo 'parent.randomBottom.location = "modules/random-bottom.php"';

echo /script

}

sleep(); pauses everything..

Comment: `while (TRUE)` is a nicer than `do ( '1' < '2' )` IMO.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has a function called `setTimeout()`, which will wait for a specified number of milliseconds and then execute some code.

In the `onload` (or document ready, whatever) of each `iframe` use `setTimeout()` to control the reload of the other `iframe`.

```
// within the iframe1 content:
<body onload="iFrame1Loaded();">
...


function iFrame1Loaded() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // put code here to tell iFrame2 to reload,
    // parent.frames["iframe2"].something.something...
  }, 20000);
}
```

And then basically the same thing in your iFrame2, with the 1s and 2s reversed...

More info about `setTimeout()` is available at the [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout).

*Note: do not attempt to implement your own `sleep()` function in JavaScript, because it will lock up the browser - the user won't be able to scroll, it won't repaint, etc., until the sleep is over.*